# Are subgraphs of a minimum spanning tree, also minimum spanning trees?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, computer-science

Clarification: MST = minimum spanning tree

Say I take some complete, weighted graph $G$ - I create a MST of the graph then split $G$ into 2 trees $T_1$ and $T_2$ by removing some edge connecting them called $uv$. My question is, that if I were to take the subgraph of all nodes constuting $T_1$ and $T_2$ and the edges originally connecting them in $G$, would the MSTs of these subgraphs be equivalent to the original MSTs $T_1$ and $T_2$? That is, are the subgraphs of a MST equal to the MSTs of the subgraphs?

Comment: Well, if $T_1$ was not a MST on its induced subgraph, then you could make lower-weighted tree $T_1'$ on that subgraph.  Connecting $T_1'$ to $T_2$ via the edge you deleted then gives a lower weighted tree than your original MST.

Comment: By the way, standard notation for the type of subgraph you are talking about is an 'induced' subgraph. If $X\subset V(G)$, then $G[X]$ is the graph with vertices $X$ and whose edges are all the edges in $G$ which have both endpoints in $X$. So the subgraphs you are describing above are $G[V(T_1)]$ and $G[V(T_2)]$.

Comment: @JairTaylor please submit this as an answer with a bit more clarification (I get your reasoning, but for future people who view this thread) so I can accept it and close this question :)

Comment: @AmmarTarajia I'll let you answer the question yourself, if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will prove the following Lemma, which answers the question you are asking.

> $G$ be a graph with vertex set $V$, and let $T$ be a  minimum spanning tree of $V$. Let $T_1$ be any subtree of $T$, and let $W$ be the vertex set of $T_1$. Then $T_1$ is also an MST of $G[W]$, the subgraph of $G$ induced by $W$.

To prove this, let $T_1'$ be any other spanning tree of $G[W]$. Consider the graph $T'$, with vertex set $V$, whose edge set $E(T')$ is given by
$$
E(T')=(E(T)\setminus E(T_1))\cup E(T_1')
$$

That is, take $T$, remove the edges of $T_1$, then add in the edges of $T_1'$. I claim that $T'$ is a spanning tree of $G$. To see this, note

- $T'$ is connected. Indeed, for any vertices $v_1,v_2\in V$, there is a path in $T$ connecting them, which can be modified to be a path in $T'$ by replacing the portion of the path that lies in $T_1$ with a corresponding path in $T_1'$.
- $T'$ has the same number of edges as $T$.

Since $T'$ is a connected graph with $|V|-1$ edges, it is a tree on the same vertex set as $G$, and therefore a spanning tree.

Now, since $T$ was an MST for $G$, we conclude that $w(T')\ge w(T)$. Since $w(T)=w(T_1)+w(T\setminus T_1)$, and $w(T')=w(T_1')+w(T\setminus T_1)$, it follows that $w(T_1')\ge w(T_1)$, thus proving the minimality of $T_1$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes; if the subgraphs created by taking the nodes and edges from $T_1$ and $T_2$ had a smaller weight than the subgraphs of the minimum spanning tree, and were combined with the original graph by adding the edge $uv$ back, the resulting graph would be a minimum spanning tree of $G$ but with a smaller weight than the original minimum spanning tree created for $G$.

This leads to a contradiction as the definition of a minimum spanning tree is such that the sum of the weights of the edges used to construct it are a minimum, hence, a smaller minimum spanning tree for $G$ cannot exist - therefore, $T_1$ and $T_2$ have to have already been minimum spanning trees as the sum of the weights of the edges in them cannot be decreased and they are already connected trees - hence fitting the definition of a minimum spanning tree.

Comment: This is a little unclear.  It sounds like you're taking apart a tree and putting the same tree back together and pointing out that its weight must be the same - which we already know.

Comment: I'd phrase this a more precisely, specifically indicating which trees you are talking about and how their weights compare.  Use the definition of min-spanning-tree: you need to show (I think, based on your original question) that if $T_1'$ is any other tree on the subgraph induced by the vertices of $T$, then $w(T_1') \geq w(T_1)$ where $w$ is the weighting function.